# setText() on a TextView only works sometimes (Android)

Tags: android, text, textview

```
try {
    answerField.setText("Unscrambling...This may take a minute");
    BufferedInputStream(getAssets().open("wordlist.txt"));
    BufferedInputStream[] textfile = new BufferedInputStream[28];
    for(int i = 0; i<28; i++){
        textfile[i] = new BufferedInputStream(getAssets().open(i+1+".txt"));
        }
    answerField.setText(Unscramble.go(tField.getText()+"", textfile));
```

My issue is with the line answerField.setText("Unscrambling...This may take a minute");

If the code is as-is, then this line will do nothing, but, if I take away the last line of the code answerField.setText(Unscramble.go(tField.getText()+"", textfile)); it works find and the TextView says "Unscrambling...this may take a minute"

The goal is for it to have that message until the program is done unscrambling, then it will have the results.

Any help would be really greatly appreciated, as I have no clue what I am doing or why this is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the UI does not update between the first call to `setText` and the second. One solution, as @AVD mentioned, is to use [`Toast`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html).

The other solution, which I believe is recommended, is to use [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). The idea here would be to set your text to the "Unscrambling" message in `onPreExecute`, then run your main task in `doInBackground`, then finally set the text to the `Unscramble.*` string in `onPostExecute`.

The documentation link I provided above has a great `AsyncTask` code there, which can be manipulated to handle just about anything.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as correct if it solved your issue (the little checkmark on the left). It helps others find the answers and encourages others to help you on you future questions. :)